# How to enable remote access to my PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, iptables

I have to centos server in my local network

- Server 1: 192.168.0.200
- Server 2: 192.168.0.201

On server 1, I have a PostgreSQL database

I need to access that database from server 2

On postgresql.conf I have changed `listen_addresses = 'localhost,192.168.0.201'`
and to `pg_hba.conf` i added host all all `192.168.0.0/24` trust

To Iptables i added the following:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 192.168.0.201 --sport 1024:65535 -d 192.168.0.200  --dport 5432 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s 192.168.0.200 --sport 5432 -d 0/0 --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Any idea what I did wrong...
All of this I did researching the internet, since I'm a Linux newbie

Any help is mostly welcome :)

----- UPDATE----
Changed listen_addresses = '*'
But still not working...
Also from another server I tryed: nc -z -w5 192.168.0.200 5432; echo $?
And I got a 1 as a result, so no conection...
I guess the problem are the iptables.. any idea?

----- UPDATE----
Found it.. this system is Centos 7, so it seems it does not use iptables... I added

## firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=5432/tcp --permanent

## firewall-cmd --reload

This solved my problem

Comment: Postgres is heavily locked down by default (a nice security feature) but a super-quick google search turns up this which should help you: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/postgres-allow-remote-access-tcp-connection.html

Answer (score 1):

You have the `listen_addresses` wrong. It is the address of the interface on the database server, not the address of the machine that you will be connecting from. Use 192.168.0.200, or '*' for all interfaces.